# How to validate a field to be unique for some rows using Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I'm trying to validate a model that has the following structure:

```
+------------+
| User       |
+------------+
| id         |
| username   |
| company_id |
+------------+
```

Where a user can belong to a company. Currently I'm validating the username to be unique in the users table using the following rule:

```
'username' => ["unique:users"]
```

When editing the current user I want to ignore the current row, and I do so using:

```
'username' => ["unique:users,username,10"]
```

And it works.

Now I want to validate the username to be unique *within a company*.

How can I validate a field to be unique within some rows (where company_id = some-id)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although it is not documented in the Laravel docs, it can be done by adding extra parameter that will be translated to where clauses.

The following will do what you requested:

```
'username' => ["unique:users,username,10,id,company_id,31"]
```

It will be translated into a SQL statement as follow:

```
select 
  count(*) 
from 
  users 
where username   =  ?
  and id         <> 10
  and company_id =  31
```